# Yii2 migration can't find database

Tags: php, migration, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to migrate two table from extension created by me. I've created it on `XAMPP` and my migration worked fine there ( tested it few times ). Then I decided to test it on another server and what I get as an error is:

```
Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ivailo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

in Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:624

Stack trace:
#0 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(996): yii\db\Connection->open()
#1 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(983): yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()
#2 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(253): yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()
#3 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(1143): yii\db\Command->prepare(true)
#4 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(399): yii\db\Command->queryInternal('fetchAll', NULL)
#5 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\mysql\Schema.php(312): yii\db\Command->queryAll()
#6 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\mysql\Schema.php(125): yii\db\mysql\Schema->findColumns(Object(yii\db\TableSchema))
#7 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php(744): yii\db\mysql\Schema->loadTableSchema('migration')
#8 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php(194): yii\db\Schema->getTableMetadata('{{%migration}}', 'schema', true)
#9 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\MigrateController.php(210): yii\db\Schema->getTableSchema('{{%migration}}
', true)
#10 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController.php(875): yii\console\controllers\MigrateControlle
r->getMigrationHistory(NULL)
#11 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController.php(166): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateContr
oller->getNewMigrations()
#12 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionUp(0)
#13 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#15 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Controller.php(148): yii\base\Controller->runAction('up', Array)
#16 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\console\Controller->runAction('up', Array)
#17 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate/up', Array)
#18 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate/up', Array)
#19 Z:\extension\slide\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request
))
#20 Z:\extension\slide\yii(23): yii\base\Application->run()
#21 {main}
```

My Yii2 is fresh installed one. Only added the extension via composer. Database configuration is correct ( user and password that we are using for years ). I've created test table and executed one line `Yii::$app->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'testname')')` and that passed fine. That way I decide that the connection is ok. But with console migration `php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/********/*******/migrations` it gave me the error above. Want to mention that I am not familiar with our server configurations ( All I know is OS: Ubuntu 14.04 H: Apache2 ) and system administrating at all if the problem is about that somehow. Thank you in advance!

Comment: was your test run in the console as well? you might have missed the config files in `console/main.php` and `console/main-local.php`

Comment: you are talking about your live server where you are unable to run the migration, did you initialized the environment when deployed on live.